# Angular CLI not copying assets folder to dist

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, ng-build

I have an app that was in Angular 4 with a custom build system. I am trying to convert it to Angular 6 using `ng-cli`. However, I am having trouble getting the `ng build` command to copy the `src/assets` folder to `dist`.

This is the relevant part of my **angular.json** file:

```
"projects": {
  "client": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "prefix": "app",
    "schematics": {},
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "outputPath": "dist/client",
          "index": "src/index.html",
          "main": "src/main.ts",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "assets": [
            "src/assets"
          ],
          "styles": [
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "src/styles/styles.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
          ]
        }
.
.
.
... rest of angular.json
```

and my assets folder is also **not empty**:

[image: assets folder]

I have a css file that references some of the files in `assets/fonts/`, so the CLI just places those files in the root of the `dist` folder, instead of `dist/assets` and **does not copy** the other files.

**Responding to answers here as well:**

It was `"src/assets"` originally. That didn't work. So I tried with `"./src/assets"` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with an asp.net core and angular project and the below setup in angular.json worked:

```
"assets": [
   {
    "glob":"**/*",
    "input":"src/assets/",
    "output":"assets/"
   }
 ],
```